# How to query Azure Data Lake?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

Coming from the database world, when we have something related to Data we use a ui tool to query data. Be it big or small.

Is there anything like SSMS, SQL WorkBench (For Big Data Redshift), Athena (Query Big Data S3) for Azure Data Lake?

I see Data Lake Analytics just queries the data and store it in file. Is there is anyway to query the data on Azure Data Lake via a UI Tool or WebBased Tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not (yet). Sure, you can run a query using the portal or using Visual Studio ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-get-started)) or Visual Studio  Code ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-for-vscode)) but all those tools will provide access to the generated file (which can be easily obtained or previewed)

Main reason is that u-sql / data lake analytics is geared toward long running jobs (that can take up from a few minutes to hours) to process the vast amount of data. Keeping that in mind you can hopefully better understand why these kind of direct query tooling is not (yet?) available.

EDIT: try upvoting [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/11266677-support-interactive-workloads-within-adl-analytics) on the feedback site. What you are asking is a highly requested feature.

Comment: That is such a junk to hear about a database product. No problem, this is not the first time being upset with Azure products. Long way to go to say it is a cloud service that is usable for public.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Azure Data Explorer form here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/
Upload, download, and manage Azure blobs, files, queues, and tables, as well as Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Data Lake Storage entities. Easily access virtual machine disks, and work with either Azure Resource Manager or classic storage accounts. Manage and configure cross-origin resource sharing rules

Answer (score 0):

You can create External table in SQL Server pointing to Data Lake Files.Only thing is we have to take care of the schema changes manually.

Comment: Tried that option. It is very slow as hell. Long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Spark SQL through azure data bricks to query Azure Data Lake Files.